# How to calculate a good hash code for a huge list of strings?

Tags: java, string, performance, hash, hashcode

What is the best way to calculate hash code based on values of these string in one pass?

With good I mean that it needs to be:

1 - fast: I need to get hash code for huge list (10^3..10^8 items) of short strings.

2 - identify the whole list of data so many list with maybe only couple of different strings must have different hash codes

How to do it in Java?

Maybe there is a way to use existing string hash code, but how to merge many hash codes calculated for separate strings?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want the hash code for?  Do you just want one hash, or one for each string?

Comment: Do you want **hash code** values like java already has `hashCode()` method on String which returns an int or, do you want hash values like MD5 digest?

Comment: Why not use the inbuilt `hashCode()` method? `List` implementations that extends `AbstractList` do count its value from the hash codes of its elements.

Comment: Must the hash code be order-sensitive? Ie should the hash code for `{"a", "b", "c"}` be the same or different than the hash code for `{"a", "c", "b"}`?

Comment: This question is way too ambiguous .... and the OP has not clarified it.   Time to close it ...

Comment: @Natix What if we want to overwrite the hashCode() method in Java? What are some good options for doing so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

create a placeholder class for you strings and then use [CRC32 class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html). its simple and fast:

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public class HugeStringCollection {
    private Collection<String> strings;

    public HugeStringCollection(Collection<String> strings) {
        this.strings = strings;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        for(String string : strings) {
            crc.update(string.getBytes())
        }

        return (int)( crc.getValue() );
    }
}
```

if the collection itself is immutable, you can compute the hash once and store it for lates reuse.

Comment: it has been widely used in file processing for years, e.g. in ZIP compression

Comment: @mantrid how do you convert this to work for an arraylist of Characters? as I guess we don't have getBytes for character!?

Comment: `String.join(myArrayList).getBytes()` I think.